# Javascript Array Index Minus One

Tags: javascript

Is it allowed to do something like `Array[i - 1]` in javascript? Assuming that i and i-1 are proper indexes of the Array.

I am wondering because it seems to give me errors but I don't know if the error is how I refer to indexes.

Furthermore, is it possible to do something like `Array[Array.length - 1]`?

The actual error is with this:

```
input = input.split('\n');
    for (var i = 1; i < input.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++){
            process.stdout.write(input[i][j]);
            process.stdout.write(input[i][j - 1]);
            process.stdout.write(input[i][input[i].length - 1 - j]);
            process.stdout.write(input[i][input[i].length - j]);
          if (input[i][j] - input[i][j - 1] !== input[i][input[i].length - 1 - j] - input[i][input[i].length - j]){

          }  
        }

    }
```

Of the `process.stdout.write` statements, only the first outputs anything.

Comment: Yes. You can put any sort of expression you want inside `[ ]` so long as it evaluates to a number or a string. Post your actual code and the actual errors you're getting.

Comment: What "errors" are you getting?  You can put any expression you want inside the `[]`.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to use `a.length - 1` as index to the array, in fact it is used to get the last element from array

Comment: Try avoiding plain yes/no questions. Add your code and errors to make your question more *valuable*.

Comment: Updated the question, my bad.

Comment: `input[i][j - 1]`.  On the 1st loop, `i` is set to `1` and `j` is set to `0`.  `input[i][-1]` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it`s possible.

See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/hca4cecc/

```
var myObj = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
alert(myObj[2-1+3]);
```

Edit:
With your updated information: There is a bug. The [j-1] is -1 in the first loop and your code should crash.